# additional constraint is created when device rotation changes

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a subview with its constraint that has reference to super view via IBOutlet, I'm changing the constraint by deactivating it then giving new value and activating again , this works fine and no warnings but the problem occurs when device rotates and it seems another constraint is getting added ( the constraint that I've added in storyboard)
code:

```
bottomViewBottomConstraint.isActive = false
if self.isHide {
    bottomViewBottomConstraint = bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.bottomAnchor,constant:0)
}
else {
    bottomViewBottomConstraint = bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.bottomAnchor,constant:bottomView.frame.height + 50)
}
bottomViewBottomConstraint.isActive = true
```

warning after rotation:

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fdce60 UIView:0x7fc034f050b0.bottom == PlayKit.PlayerView:0x7fc034f69870.bottom + 143.333   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fe3480 'bottomViewId' V:[UIView:0x7fc034f050b0]-(0)-|   (active, names: 
> '|':PlayKit.PlayerView:0x7fc034f69870 )>"
> ```

Bottom view storyboard constraint
[image]

Comment: There is no need to deactivate a constraint just in order to change its constant. Just set the constant!

Comment: @matt Can you answer as to why the above code is not working properly?

Comment: @matt thanks for replying , actually my problem gone with playing with constant but in case of my situation why new constraint is added when device rotates it doesn't make sense

Comment: You tell me. Where is the 143.333 coming from ? Use the View Debugger to find out. Maybe you created a conditional constraint in the storyboard. How do I know?

Comment: @matt thats for view's bottomView.frame.height , the problem ( warning ) occurs only when device rotates

Comment: The point is that you have not given enough information for anyone to answer. Only you know the facts so only you can debug. Debug! Use the View Debugger.

Comment: @matt I don't know what else should I provided ? actually I debugged and telling you new constraint is added when device rotates and before that everything works fine ( when device doesnt rotate above code works without any waning )

Comment: Constraints are not added by magic. If a new constraint is really being added it's because you asked for that constraint to be added. It might have something to do with your mysterious phrase "the constraint that I've added in the storyboard", but as I say, it's impossible to tell from here.

Comment: mohammad jan, do you know how to use view debug hierarchy? If so then take a snapshot of its constraints when its rotated and edit the question with it...

Comment: @matt I added storyboard constraint screenshot to post ... the point is the constraint is added actually it seems so because before that no warning and no additional constraint being added ... I have no other code other than in post... my question is why changing device orientation effects my constraint to being added? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done what I suggested? Run the app, rotate it, pause it in the View Debugger, and _look_ to see what's going on.

Comment: Also this line makes no sense: `bottomViewBottomConstraint = bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.bottomAnchor,constant:bottomView.frame.height + 50)` You should never ever set a constraint in terms of the _frame_ of anything. That might be the issue right there.

Comment: where are you calling your code snippet from?

Answer (score 0):

You need it one in `viewDidLoad`

```
var bottomViewBottomConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

---

```
bottomViewBottomConstraint = bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerView.bottomAnchor,constant:0)
```

---

and play with constant

```
bottomViewBottomConstraint.constant = self.isHide ? 0 :   bottomView.frame.height + 50
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: But why does OP's code not work properly? It looks fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but in my case why new constraint is only added when device rotates and not before that and everything works perfectly

Comment: where you put this code ?? , also do you write any thing inside viewWillTransition ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan no nothing in viewWillTranstion